# Why do we need `nil`?

Tags: lisp, scheme, s-expression

I do not see why we need `nil` [1] when to `cons` a sequence (so-called proper list) of items. It seems to me we can achieve the same goal by using the so-called improper list (`cons`-ed pairs without an ending `nil`) alone. Since Lisps [2] have already provided a primitive procedure to distinguish between a `pair?` and an atom (some implementations even provide `atom?`), when defining a procedure on a list, e.g., `length`, I can do the same with just dotted-pairs, as shown below:

```
(define len
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((pair? l) (+ 1 (len (cdr l))))
          (else 1) ) ) )
```

It is obvious that we can apply this procedure to an improper list like `'(1 . (2 . 3))` to get the expected answer `3`, in contrast to the traditional `(length '(1 2 3))`.

I'd like to hear any opinions in defense of the necessity of `nil`. Thanks in advance.

[1] Let's ignore the debate among `nil`/`NIL`, `'()` and `()`.

[2] Here it means the Lisp family of languages.

Comment: think of what would happen if you had a list of lists? and you'll see why `nil` is needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Working with lists without `nil` (or `'()`) would be like doing arithmetic without zero. Using only pairs without `nil`, how would we represent an empty list, or a singleton list `'(1)`?

It gets worse: since lists don't have to be lists of atoms, but can contain other lists, how would we represent the nested list `'(1 2 (3 4))`? If we do the following conversions:

```
'(3 4) => '(3 . 4)
'(1 2 x) => '(1 . (2 . x)) == '(1 2 . x)
```

we get:

```
'(1 2 (3 4)) => '(1 . (2 . (3 . 4))) == '(1 2 3 . 4)
```

But also:

```
'(1 2 3 4) => '(1 . (2 . (3 . 4))) == '(1 2 3 . 4)
```

So constructing lists only using pairs and no `nil` prevents us from distinguishing between a nested list structure and a flat list, at least at the end of the list. You can still include nested lists as any element except the last, so now there's a strange and arbitrary limitation on what the elements of a list can be.

More theoretically, proper lists are an inductively defined data type: a list is either the empty list, or it has a `first` element, which can be anything, and a `rest`, which is *always* another list defined in the same way. Take away the empty list, and now you have a data type where the `rest` *might* be another list, or it might be the last element of the list. We can't tell except by passing it to `pair?`, which leads to the problem with nested listing above. Keeping `nil` around lets us have whatever we like as list elements, and allows us to distinguish between `1`, `'(1)`, `'((1))` and so on.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your answer. Could you give a scenario where singleton would be useful? Thanks.

Comment: I think it comes down to having a consistent interface. If you have a function that might return no items, one item, or many items, it's annoying (at the very least) to have to add special code for the one-item case. One example is parsing a string with an ambiguous grammar: the parser might fail, returning `'()`, or match once, or any number of times. Also, a nice part of Lisp is functions like `map` and `filter` that work on a list of `<something>` without having to know its internal details. These would be harder to write without the inductive definition of a proper list.

Comment: To clarify a bit more: Suppose we changed the parsing/matching function so that in the one-match case it simply returns the plain result, instead of a singleton list. Now every user of the function has to do an extra `pair?` check on the return value before doing anything else with it. (And that might not even work: what if the results of your parser are themselves lists?) For almost all purposes, there's nothing inherently special about a one-item list, so this is extra code and effort that adds nothing.

Comment: No problem! Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need it to represent "Nothing".