# A 'cons' in Haskell that displays like its Scheme counterpart

Tags: haskell, scheme

As an exercise, I am implementing in Haskell a 'cons' operation that forms a pair from two values of any type.  Implementing the needed data type is easy enough:

```
data Nil = Nil deriving (Eq)
data Pair a b = Cons a b deriving (Eq)

car (Cons x _) = x
cdr (Cons _ y) = y

caar = car . car
cdar = cdr . car
cadr = car . cdr
cddr = cdr . cdr

*Main> cddr (Cons 55 (Cons (1,2,3,4) "hello, world!"))
"hello, world!"
*Main>
```

but inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069932/what-are-improper-lists-for), I want to make the resulting pairs print out like Scheme lists would - including the infamous "improper list" (1 2 3 . 4).  My implementation (see below) is working for Char's:

```
*Main> Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' (Cons 'c' Nil))
('a' 'b' 'c')
*Main> Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' 'c')
('a' 'b' . 'c')
*Main> Cons (Cons 'a' 'b')(Cons 'c' (Cons 'd' Nil))
(('a' . 'b') 'c' 'd')
```

It's not working so well for Int's (or any other data type).  So my question is: how can I make this work for other data types?  i.e., I want it to work like this:

```
*Main> Cons 5 (Cons "hello" (Cons False Nil))
(5 "hello" False)
```

My current full implementation follows:

```
data Nil = Nil deriving (Eq)
data Pair a b = Cons a b deriving (Eq)

car (Cons x _) = x
cdr (Cons _ y) = y

caar = car . car
cdar = cdr . car
cadr = car . cdr
cddr = cdr . cdr

instance Show Nil where show _ = "()"

class ShowPair a where
  showRight::a->String

instance (Show a, ShowPair a, ShowPair b)=>Show (Pair a b) where
  show (Cons car cdr) = "(" ++ (show car) ++ (showRight cdr) ++ ")"

instance (Show a, ShowPair a, ShowPair b)=>ShowPair (Pair a b) where
  showRight (Cons car cdr) = " " ++ (show car) ++ (showRight cdr)

instance ShowPair Char where
  showRight x = " . " ++ show x

instance ShowPair Int where
  showRight x = " . " ++ show x

instance ShowPair Nil where
  showRight _ = ""
```

Comment: Haskell comes with a builtin operation that can form a pair from two values of any type: `(a, b)`. It can be spelled `(,) a b` if you want to be able to use it as you would a function. `()` then takes the part of your `Nil`. `car` is then spelled `fst`, and `cdr` is `snd`.

Comment: @Ben Understood - I knew it was likely that I was doing some wheel reinvention here.  Is there any way to get pairs produced with (,) to print out like Scheme lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option. First, enable these extensions by putting this line at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances#-}
```

Next, remove your `ShowPair` instances for `Char` and `Int`.

Now add a `ShowPair` instance for anything with `Show`:

```
instance Show a => ShowPair a where showRight = (" . " ++) . show
```

This now ensures that any type `a` which is an instance of `Show` is also an instance of `ShowPair` where it is shown by prepending a `.` to its normal string form. However, if a type has a more specific `ShowPair` instance (e.g. `Nil`), Haskell will use that one instead.

This is not part of standard Haskell, so you need to enable the three language extensions. Look at [How to write an instance for all types in another type class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877541/how-to-write-an-instance-for-all-types-in-another-type-class/8877609#8877609) for more information on *why* you need the extensions.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation, and the link to the related post!

Answer (score 2):

Ben in the comments to the question mentions the native pair type, which I'm going to use in this answer.  I'm also going to substitute your `Nil` with the Haskell unit type `()`.

This is a bit outside what you're asking, but I think it's worth saying.  It is difficult in Haskell to capture the notion of a "list" in Scheme unless you "cheat" and use an extension like [`Data.Dynamic`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html).  This is because from the point of view of "pure," unextended Haskell, it is difficult if not impossible to assign all Scheme lists the same type.  This means that while Scheme allows you to write functions that take any list, proper or improper, you're going to have a hard time doing the same in Haskell (and for good reason; improper "lists" should probably not exist anyway).

So for example, you've basically chosen to use `(a, b)` as the type of Scheme-like pairs.  Now suppose we have these Scheme lists:

```
(define zero  '())
(define one   '(1))
(define two   '(1 2))
(define three '(1 2 3))
(define four  '(1 2 3 4))
```

Here's a simple translation in terms of Haskell pairs, which corresponds to the way you're doing it:

```
zero :: ()
zero = ()

one :: (Integer, ())
one = (1, ())

two :: (Integer, (Integer, ()))
two = (1, (2, ()))

three :: (Integer, (Integer, (Integer, ())))
three = (1, (2, (3, ())))

four :: (Integer, (Integer, (Integer, (Integer, ()))))
four = (1, (2, (3, (4, ()))))
```

The key thing is that in Scheme you can easily write a function that ranges over all lists:

```
(define (reverse list)
 (foldl cons '() list))

(define (filter pred? list)
  (foldr (lambda (elem rest)
           (if (pred? elem)
               (cons elem rest)
               rest))
         '()
         list))

(define (foldl fn init list)
  (if (null? list)
      init
      (foldl fn (fn (car list) init) (cdr list))))

(define (foldr fn init list)
  (if (null? list)
      init
      (fn (car list)
          (foldr fn init (cdr list)))))
```

In this Haskell translation, you cannot do that easily at all, because "lists" of different lengths have different types.  And it gets worse when you consider the difference between `reverse` (which takes a list of length *n* and produces a list of length *n*) and `filter` (which takes a list of length *n* and produces a list of length *m* ≤ *n* such that *m* can only be known at runtime).

Comment: Hmm, yes - I see how it would get awkward to try to implement `filter` and `reverse` in Haskell for a "list of whatevers" - even though cadr, cddr etc. are pretty easy