# Linked Lists:How can we tell if the usage of a dummy node is absolute necessity?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, computer-science

I am doing a refresher on CS fundamentals.
I have a question on linked lists.

There are some cases that a dummy node is used (in the head of the list mainly) to assist in the implementation.

I see that if it is missing (i.e. if an approach without using a dummy node is followed) the code becomes "messy" (at least I do it messy since I am rusty on these stuff....)

I was wondering are there cases that an algorithm is **not** possible to be solved **without** using a dummy node?
Can you give an example?

And are there specific characteristics of the problem at hand that give away that a dummy node is the only way to go?

Note: I don't tag a specific language but just in case my prefered is Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not any algorithms that are not possible without having a dummy node, it is just there for convenience and keeping the code clean. Without a dummy you have to take special consideration e.g. when deleting the last node of a linked list or traversing an empty linked list – in these cases the dummy acts as a sentinel that keeps the core algorithm for traversal and removal simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of having a dummy node (called a *sentinel* in some texts) is that it's no longer necessary to check for null elements in the list, in a way, it's an instance of the [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern, making the implementation of some algorithms simpler.

Other than that, there won't be any difference in the algorithms that can be solved using either implementation (with or without a dummy node). For example, Oracle's implementation of the LinkedList class uses a dummy node, but other vendors are free to write a dummy-less version of the class, since it's an implementation detail that won't make any difference to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Without some way of unambiguously marking the end of the list, it can be impossible to unambiguously interpret nested lists. See: [Why do we need `nil`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062043/why-do-we-need-nil)

You could, of course check if a node is the final node by keeping a pointer to it, but that is unattractive in no small part because it is inefficient.

Comment: May be I am missunderstanding your reference but a `null` pointer marking the end of the list is not a dummy node.At least I never thought of it that way.A dummy node in the end would be a non `null` node having a special value indicating the end.Or am I missunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @user384706: Yes, you are misunderstanding my answer, and the linked question. `nil` is not the same thing as a null pointer. Java is not the only programming language.